# Nagios installation issue

Tags: centos6

I am using centos6.4 and i am trying to install nagios on that system, i follow these steps:

1) Download and install repo

```
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

2) Start installation

After installation i found some error:

```
Error: Package: nagios-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php
Error: Package: nagios-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: httpd
Error: Package: nagios-plugins-mysql-1.4.16-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Error: Package: nagios-plugins-mysql-1.4.16-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
```

I have check httpd and installed php. They're both working fine but I'm still unable to start nagios.

Comment: How have you checked/installed these dependencies?

Comment: i apply command #httpd status and result was showing status of apache.

Comment: and if i am trying to install it by yum command: yum install php/httpd 
showing result:root@supernova [~]# yum install php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php available.
Error: Nothing to do
</pre> same with httpd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that php and http are installed

```
yum list | grep php
yum list | grep http
```

Verify that you have the necessary repos active

```
yum repolist

repo id                  repo name              status
centos6-x86_64           CentOS 6               13,152
centos6-x86_64-updates   CentOS 6 Updates       5,771
epel6-centos6-x86_64     EPEL 6 for CentOS 6    278
```

Very the package you want to install

```
yum search php
yum search http
```

Install the necessary packages

From a quick look at your comments I don't think you have all the necessary repos enabled.  It looked like you were only looking at epel.  If this is the case then it could be why you are not finding php and httpd.

Comment: Just a small tip, but `yum list php httpd` will be much faster.